# Does XFX 750i support a solid state drive

Tags: ssd

I have XFX 750i motherboard. I want to purchase a Kingston SSD 120GB. Before purchasing this SSD I would like to know whether my motherboard will support it or not??

Comment: Your motherboard has 4 SATA II slots.  This means you can use the SSD but its speed will be limited because it will be limited to SATA II speeds.  I can't make a complete answer out of this comment maybe somebody else can.

Comment: well thanks for responding the question. I have already purchased ssd and it is working fine. And thanks for telling me that it will work better if I upgrade to sataIII motherboard.